# Trying to print results of Apache Solr Search

Tags: 7, search

I'm trying to print to Drupal message, the indexed items as an object in Drupal.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function resource_library_search_apachesolr_process_results(&$results, DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query){
    drupal_get_message(print_r($results, true));

    }
```

I'm not seeing any results on any of my search pages - am I doing anything wrong? How do I get information on the indexed items as an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **print** to the drupal messages, you need to use `drupal_set_message` instead of `drupal_get_message` first.